# Double request to the page

Tags: javascript, performance, express

I run lighthouse in chrome dev tools and get this in performance trace tab.
[network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsiBT.png)

It has a double request and I try to understand what causes it. As you can see, first paint starts only after the second req ended.

I've tried `req.connection.setTimeout(60 * 1000);` but it doesn't work. Its also not a "favicon case".

upd.

The first request has

```
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
```

the second

```
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not the preflight request? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: In server logs I see that router and render app function call twice, but I will check headers, thanks.